# How to access field level Graphql directive with graphql-spqr

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java, graphql-spqr

Given a graphql Query

```
query @my (arg:1) {
  foo @my (arg:2) {
    bar @my (arg:3)
    foobar @my (arg:4)
  }
}
```

And graphql server implementation using `graphql-spqr`

```java
@GraphQLType(name="foo")
public class Foo{
   @GraphQLQuery(name="bar")
   public String bar;
   @GraphQLQuery(name="foobar")
   public String foobar;
}
```

```java
@GraphQLDirective(name="my", locations = {QUERY, FIELD} )
public class MyGraphqlDirective{
  @GraphqlInputField("arg")
  public int arg;
}
```

```java
public class GraphqlService{
   @GraphQLQuery(name = "foo")
   public Foo foo(@Nullable @GraphQLDirective(name="my") MyGraphqlDirective my){
      Foo foo=new Foo();
      if(my!=null){
         foo.bar = String.valueOf(my.arg);
         foo.foobar = String.valueOf(my.arg);
      }
      return foo;
   }
}
```

I have access to `(arg:2)` on the query foo, if it is exists, and fallback to `(arg:1)` if that was absent.

However, I have problem if I would like to read that on field foo and foobar.

I'd want to, make it not readable, abusing `@GraphqlContext` for every single field.
Is there any easier way to archive some simple logic (e.g. uppercase, locale, rounding, number format) on field level.

---

Also tried `dataFetchingEnvironment.getSelectionSet().get().getSubField("edge/node/foo/bar").getSingleField().getDirective()` which doesn't take the Directive from parent

---

Comment: tried dataFetchingEnvironment.getSelectionSet()

Comment: Can you provide a sample repo and a sample postman request to test?